# Java Creating a two-dimensional linked list(data structure)

Tags: java, data-structures

so using a singly-linked approach, I'm trying to create a two dimensional linked list(matrix). The matrix will be constructed with specified dimension(ex 3x4 matrix). Below is my code.

```
class MLink{
public MLink nextCol;
public MLink nextRow;
public long data;
//----------------------------------
MLink(long data){
    this.data = data;
    nextCol = null;
    nextRow = null;
}
//----------------------------------
public void displayLink(){
    System.out.print("{"+data+"} ");
}
//----------------------------------
}// end class MList

class MLinkList{
private MLink first;
private MLink current;
private int rows;
private int cols;
//----------------------------------
MLinkList(int rows, int cols){
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    MLink newLink = new MLink(0);
    first = newLink;
    current = first;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        current.nextRow = new MLink(0);
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            current.nextCol = new MLink(0);
        }
    }
}
//----------------------------------
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (first==null);
}
//----------------------------------




}//end class MLinkList
public class MatrixListApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MLinkList q = new MLinkList(3,4);

}

}
```

I have to admit that I haven't made much progress because I got stuck at initializing the matrix in the MLinkList constructor. What I wanna do is I want to fill up the matrix with MLinks with 0 and then work my way up from there. I assume that I would have to move my **current** along the matrix to fill the matrix but how can I do so?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a linked list structure if you know the size of the matrix upfront?

Comment: Just to practice I guess. It's a problem from the book. I'm pretty sure array would be a better fit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two current values, the current row and the current cell in the current column.

To move alone the columns you would do `currentCell = curretnCell.nextCol;`

Comment: thank you for the reply. I've made a bit of progress adopting your solution. But I seem to be making 5 cells(when I put 2x2) instead of 4. Can you point out the part that I messed up?

Comment: MLink currentCol;
  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   currentCol = current;
   for(int j=1;j<cols;j++){
    currentCol.nextCol = new MLink(0);
    currentCol = currentCol.nextCol;
   }
   current.nextRow = new MLink(0);
   current = current.nextRow;
  }